# How to speed up the script code in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I spend a lot of time to speed up the below script but I cannot. Could you help me or suggest any way to speed up it? This is my code

```
import numpy as np
import time
#Unchange
input = np.random.randn(300,400,500)
step_x = 30
step_y = 40
step_z = 50
lst_x = np.arange(0, input.shape[0] + step_x, step_x)
lst_y = np.arange(0, input.shape[1] + step_y, step_y)
lst_z = np.arange(0, input.shape[2] + step_z, step_z)
results = np.zeros((input.shape))
t0 = time.time()
for i in range(len(lst_x)):
  for j in range(len(lst_y)):
      for k in range(len(lst_z)):
          xx= lst_x[i]
          yy= lst_y[j]
          zz= lst_z[k]
          patch = input[xx : xx + step_x, yy : yy + step_y, zz : zz + step_z]          
          patch_added = np.random.randn(patch.shape[0],patch.shape[1],patch.shape[2]) + patch
          results[xx : xx + step_x, yy : yy + step_y, zz : zz + step_z] += patch_added
print ('Time consumption: ', time.time()-t0)
```

You can run online at https://repl.it/repls/PleasingGhostwhiteNetworking

Currently, it takes 11 seconds on the Repl.it. Can you make it faster in python 3?

**Update:** I have an original array input that is 3D array. From the array, I will extract into patches with the size of 30x40x50 and process on the patch. After that, the processed patches will be assigned into the results array with location same with the location of the patches in the `input`

Comment: Please check ["Which site?"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129598/which-computer-science-programming-stack-exchange-do-i-post-in) for general issues and ["Code Review or not?"](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users/5778#5778)

Comment: I have an original array `input` that is 3D array. From the array, I will extract into patches with the size of `30x40x50` and process on the patch. After that, I will assign the processed patch to the results at the same position of the patch

Comment: @Prune My understanding was that questions about improving performance are a bit of a grey area as to whether they go in SO or Code Review.

Comment: Dear all, I have updated my question to more clear. Please upvote it

Comment: At the very least, you're not using `i`/`j`/`k` for anything, but just getting rid of those `enumerate()`s will probably not make your code much faster.

Comment: Thanks. I updated it

Comment: No, you just used a different name for the variable. I think @AKX was suggesting that you don't use the `enumerate` function at all and just do `for xx in lst_x:`

Comment: Just changing those variables to underscores doesn't matter; you'd also have to get rid of the `enumerate()` calls.

Comment: Updated it. Is it correct?

Answer (score 2):

Changing

```
patch_added = np.random.randn(patch.shape[0],patch.shape[1],patch.shape[2]) + patch
```

to

```
patch_added = np.zeros(patch.shape) + patch
```

drops "Time consumption" down to about 2 seconds instead of 10-11.

This means the script is mostly spending its time generating random numbers.

Comment: Thanks. But the problem is that patch_added must be random generated

Comment: Well, then it's just going to take a while to generate those random numbers and sum them up. Most of the time is spent there; it's not worth it to micro-optimize everything else around it.